# Save master grid data and detail grid data in kendo

Tags: spring-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using spring mvc and kendo UI hierarchical grid where my master grid row will have another grid as its child in a hierarchical way. I want to perform the CRUD operation for both master and child grids on click of common save change button. But I have no idea how to do this as i am new to this Kendo. Can any help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but it not really good because they are saved independently.if you have better solution, let me know.
You can try:

create a javascript function on save button

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {

    $("#master_grid_id").data("kendoGrid").saveChanges();
    $("#master_grid_id").find(".k-grid").each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).data("kendoGrid").saveChanges();
    });

});
```